# How to compile multiple less files into multiple corresponding css files using webassets

Tags: python, webassets

I have the following Bundle configuration:

```
less = Bundle('**/*.less',
          filters='less', output='static/less.%(version)s.css')
```

Is it possible to compile the different less files into corresponding css files (in debug mode)? This configuration creates one css file.